# How do I create a navigation Item in Visual Studio 2017 Extensions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have followed [this](https://binary-stuff.com/post/getting-start-with-a-team-explorer-plugin-for-vs-2013-part-2) post to get a menu item running in Visual Studio 2013, but I have been unable to get the navigation item working, either by upgrading the original code to 2017, or by following the same instructions in VS 2017.
In VS 2013 I can create a class as below and it gets loaded automatically, but not in the 2017 version.

```
 [TeamExplorerNavigationItem(GuidList.sampleTeamExplorerNavigationItem, 100)]
public class SampleTeamExplorerNavigationItem : ITeamExplorerNavigationItem
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key missing ingredient was ensuring that the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.MefComponent" Asset is added in the source.extension.vsixmanifest. Double click on the manifest file in the solution explorer and the file should open in the designer. Go to the assets page and "Add" the file. 
Additionally ensure that "System.ComponentModel.Composition" and (as suggested by Cole above) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll are referenced.

Answer (score 0):

If you use visual studio 2017, which has different steps. please following the following steps.

1. File -> New -> Project -> Extensibility -> VSIX project -> Change project name as you want -> OK
2. right click the project -> Add -> New Item -> Extensibility -> visual studio package -> change item name as you want -> Add
3. right click references -> add reference -> Browse... -> add the following dll to your project C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\15.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.dll
4. add the class named SampleTeamExplorerNavigationItem

And the following sample for your reference.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgRL2bSgNqDz2Z-ga

Comment: The Link is not working for me error "Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://1drv.ms  again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator"

Comment: arrgh the "enter" key should not save a comment, and 5 mins is not long enough to edit comments. - The Link is not working for me, but I have followed the instructions as provided. In fact this was what I did previously, the only change is the location of Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Controls.dll. This still does not work. I am using the same SampleTeamExplorerNavigationItem  class that I used for the 2013 implementation. Perhaps this is not correct.

Comment: Do you encounter any exceptions?

Comment: No, I have tried setting a break point in the constructor and it does not get called.

Comment: OK I got the sample you provided at home
I had to change a number of things to get it to build on my machine
1) Add a solution in a parent folder to allow it to find the packages
2) Add a reference to System.ComponentModel.Composition
3) I had to include the following files in the project
 a) Everyting in the Resources folder
 b) the key.snk the 
 c) SampleTeamExplorerNavigationItem.cs
 d) Resource.Designer.cs
 e) Resources.resx
 f) VsPackages.resx
I had to add references to
 a) System
 b) System.drawing
 c) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls and a using statement to reference it

Comment: Ran out of room in previous comment, it built and ran but did not work

Comment: Please share a simple demo which could reproduce the issue via onedrive.